# Using reloadRowsAtIndexPaths when the update of a NSFetchedResultsController is triggered

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have some rows of my `UITableView` that get updated and then trigger the method `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath` of the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` delegate.

I usually update the rows in the tableView using `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` with an animation, but it happens that sometimes the method is triggered because of a change that is not visible and is that case, I don't want to reload the row with an animation.

The method doesn't give the previous state of the object. Is there a way to do it (I didn't find any method of the delegate that might do)?

Answer (score 0):

If your delegate is also your `TableViewController`, you could just check your `UITableView`'s data source at the `IndexPath`. The `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` method knows the index.

Comment: The problem is when I get to the method triggered, I don't have access to the old object, so I don't know what has changed (I mean I do, but not the code...)

Comment: Why not keep a copy around ? I assume you store your data in an array for your tableView ? just store two arrays and only update one.

Comment: Yes I thought about that but was wondering if there was another/better way